# Smart contract to strore and retrieve address and ID in blockchian using mapping

Tags: solidity, blockchain, dapps, ethereumjs

I want to store  some address and their ids in blockchain using mapping and i want to know how to get the  stored addresses when searching with their respective IDs.

Answer (score 0):

When using `mapping` one of the problems is that there is no way to enumerate over the values. Whatever you store in the mapping with a key can only be accessed with that key and no other way.

So, in order to store both the mapping data and data about which entries have mapping data you have to use two different structures. One `mapping` for the actual mapping and one `array` to store information about which keys have a mapping.

If I understood your question correctly you want some way to search through the added ids.

So here's a very simple example contract. If I misunderstood and you don't need any searching possibilities you can just remove the `ids` part. With the below example you can add some functionality to search through the `ids` array:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.5;

contract Mapping {

    mapping(uint => address) map;
    uint[] ids;

    function mapAddr(address addr, uint id) public {
        map[id] = addr;
        ids.push(id);
    }

    function getAddr(uint id) public returns (address) {
        return map[id];
    }
}
```